# Refresh / Reload ember route from a component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, components, router

I have a component, that's actually a modal dialog.
When I am done with that dialog and press the "Ok" button, I want to stay on the stay page from where I opened that dialog.
Which isn't difficult.

But the problem is that the dialog changes the data (I am getting data through a REST call) so I need to refresh the route that I already am on to reflect the data changes.

Since, I am calling it from a component, I don't have  `Route` so can't call `route.refresh()`.

I tried to get the router:

`this.set('router', Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('router:main'));`

and did transition to the same page:

`_this.get('router').transitionTo('my-route')`

But since the route hasn't changed (I only opened a dialog), `transitionTo` doesn't get triggered!

Is there a way I can force trigger `transitionTo` or refresh the page that I am on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this, define `refreshCurrentRoute` method in nearest route or in application route file.

```
actions:{
 refreshCurrentRoute(){
  this.refresh();
 }
}
```

From your component, you need to call `refreshCurrentRoute` action. either you can use [ember-route-action-helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper) or by passing the closure action.

Comment: Thanks @kumkanillam!

Comment: Inject router service and call refresh method from anywhere.
https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/RouterService

Answer (score 8):

First, you can easily get the current route name by injecting the [routing service](https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/RoutingService.html) to the component.
Then, you can get the current route instance and apply its [`refresh`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh) method:

```
// app/components/a-component.js

import Component from "ember-component";
import service from "ember-service/inject";
import getOwner from "ember-owner/get";

export default Component.extend({
  routing: service("-routing"),
  actions: {
    refresh() {
      const currentRouteName = this.get("routing.currentRouteName");
      const currentRouteInstance = getOwner(this).lookup(`route:${currentRouteName}`);
      currentRouteInstance.refresh();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't the `getOwner` lookup give you the `Router` and not the `Route`? As the `refresh` method belongs to `Route` not `Router`.

Comment: the router is given via `routing.router`. The lookup is looking for a route instance this is because of the `route:` prefix of the looked-up module name.
`refresh` method indeed is a `Route` method. `currentRouteInstance.refresh();` is applying the refresh method of the `Route` instance. My solution is different from @kumkanillam's by that it does not require you to bubble up any actions.

Comment: The `currentRouteInstance` is undefined, and throws an exception on calling `refresh`. The `currentRouteName` was computed fine.

Comment: What is the currentRouteName?

Comment: It's just has a string, the name of the route: `my-route`

Comment: Strange. For some reason the lookup fails. Here is a working twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/59382cf82e82a6b0301f322c64a10ae1?openFiles=components.a-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.a-component.hbs

Comment: [RoutingService](https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/RoutingService.html) is private so its good to stay away from one. otherwise, future upgrade may not work as expected.

Comment: @Ramy Ben Aroya Yes it is strange, I tried passing it manually the route too but didn't work! Thanks though!

Comment: @EmberFreak the RouterService is now public API in the latest versions of Ember, so this can be considered safe to use (and is now injected w/o the dash prefix, just `router: service()` works). FYI to anyone finding this answer in 2019. https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.10/classes/RouterService